# How to Play Video file with E-AC3 audio to Amplifier with AC3

Tags: audio, sound-card

I have HTPC that I play movies that I download from the internet.
The file format I am using is *.MKV.
My amplifier is capable of playing DTS & AC3 formats.
I have Windows 10 on the HTPC and use the PotPlayer (formerly KMPlayer) to play the movies.
I connect my PC with SPDIF from the soundcard that is onboard the motherboard.
I hear a Stereo sound.
What should I do to be able to hear the 5.1 channels without converting the video file?
[image: PotPlayer Settings]